# passing a C structure to the python function and accessing char 2d array in python which is initialized in C

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I'm new to python. I want to send a pointer to a structure from my C code to a Python function, and then accessing the C structure from within Python.

My structure has two data members. They are

```
int num_of_ker;
char *ker_name[50];
```

Some how I got the solution from [here](http://forums.indiegamer.com/showthread.php?9464-DX7-slower-than-OpenGL&goto=nextoldest).

MyProject.i

```
%module MyProject   
%inline %{       
struct SPythoned 
{
        int num_of_ker;
        char *ker_name[50];
};
%}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

extern "C"      // only needed when compiling in C++
{
        #include "MyProject_wrap.c"
}

// struct SPythoned is defined within MyProject_wrap.c just included above


void PythonTest(void)
{

        Py_Initialize();        // Init Python
        SWIG_init();            // Initialise SWIG types
        init_MyProject();               // Init our project wrapped by Swig

        PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
        PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\"./\")");

        SPythoned Object;
        PyObject *pMod, *pGlobalDict, *pFunc, *pResult, *pArg;

        Object.num_of_ker = 2;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
                char name[50];
                sprintf(name,"kernel_%d",i);
                Object.ker_name[i]=strdup(name);
        }

        pMod = PyImport_ImportModule("PyTest"); // Load "PyTest.py" (it will create a compiled version "PyTest.pyc")

        if (pMod)
        {
                pGlobalDict = PyModule_GetDict(pMod);   // Get main dictionary

                if (pGlobalDict)
                {
                        pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pGlobalDict, "TestObject");        // Look for function TestObject

                        if (pFunc)
                        {
                                pArg = SWIG_NewPointerObj((void*)&Object, SWIGTYPE_p_SPythoned, 1);     // Get Python Object for our Structure Pointer

                                if (pArg)
                                {
                                        pResult = PyObject_CallFunction(pFunc, "O", pArg);
                                        Py_CLEAR(pResult);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        Py_Finalize();
}

int main()
{
PythonTest();
return 0;
}
```

PyTest.py

```
import MyProject

def TestObject(o):
        print  "ker_num " , o.num_of_ker
        for i in range(o.num_of_ker):
                print "kername ",o.ker_name[i]
```

In`main.cpp` I'm initializing both `num_of_ker` and `ker_name` data members. I'm able to access `num_of_ker` variable from `PyTest.py` file, but I am not getting how to access `ker_name` in `PyTest.py` file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Curious, can you share how you got this working? Don't see how your link is an answer..